# Ensuring value lives for its entire scope

Tags: rust

I have a type (specifically [CFData](https://docs.rs/core-foundation/0.9.2/core_foundation/data/struct.CFData.html) from core-foundation), whose memory is managed by C APIs and that I need to pass and receive from C functions as a `*c_void`. For simplicity, consider the following struct:

```
struct Data {
    ptr: *mut ffi::c_void,
}

impl Data {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // allocate memory via an unsafe C-API
        Self {
            ptr: std::ptr::null(), // Just so this compiles.
        }
    }

    pub fn to_raw(&self) -> *const ffi::c_void {
        self.ptr
    }
}

impl Drop for Data {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            // Free memory via a C-API
        }
    }
}
```

Its interface is safe, including `to_raw()`, since it only returns a raw pointer. It doesn't dereference it. And the caller doesn't dereference it. It's just used in a callback.

```
pub extern "C" fn called_from_C_ok(on_complete: extern "C" fn(*const ffi::c_void)) {
    let data = Data::new();

    // Do things to compute Data.
    // This is actually async code, which is why there's a completion handler.

    on_complete(data.to_raw()); // data survives through the function call
}
```

This is fine. Data is safe to manipulate, and (I strongly believe) Rust promises that `data` will live until the end of the `on_complete` function call.

On the other hand, this is not ok:

```
pub extern "C" fn called_from_C_broken(on_complete: extern "C" fn(*const ffi::c_void)) {
    let data = Data::new();
    // ...
    let ptr = data.to_raw(); // data can be dropped at this point, so ptr is dangling.
    on_complete(ptr);        // This may crash when the receiver dereferences it.
}
```

In my code, I made this mistake and it started crashing. It's easy to see why and it's easy to fix. But it's subtle, and it's easy for a future developer (me) to modify the ok version into the broken version without realizing the problem (and it may not always crash).

What I'd like to do is to ensure `data` lives as long as `ptr`. [In Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime), I'd do this with:

```
withExtendedLifetime(&data) { data in
    // ...data cannot be dropped until this closure ends...
}
```

Is there a similar construct in Rust that explicitly marks the minimum lifetime for a variable to a scope (that the optimizer may not reorder), even if it's not directly accessed? (I'm sure it's trivial to build a custom `with_extended_lifetime` in Rust, but I'm looking for a more standard solution so that it will be obvious to other developers what's going on).

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=afa546af66a6a45ba2aae8e651cb6c81)

---

I do believe the following "works" but I'm not sure how flexible it is, or if it's just replacing a more standard solution:

```
fn with_extended_lifetime<T, U, F>(value: &T, f: F) -> U
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> U,
{
    f(value)
}

    with_extended_lifetime(&data, |data| {
        let ptr = data.to_raw();
        on_complete(ptr)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer *is not* allowed to change when a value is dropped. If you assign a value to a variable (and that value is not then moved elsewhere or overwritten by assignment), it will *always* be dropped at the end of the block, not earlier.

You say that this code is incorrect:

```rust
pub extern "C" fn called_from_C_broken(on_complete: extern "C" fn(*const ffi::c_void)) {
    let data = Data::new();
    // ...
    let ptr = data.to_raw(); // data can be dropped at this point, so ptr is dangling.
    on_complete(ptr);        // This may crash when the receiver dereferences it.
}
```

but in fact `data` *may not* be dropped at that point, and this code is sound. What you may be confusing this with is the mistake of *not assigning the value to a variable:*

```rust
    let ptr = Data::new().to_raw();
    on_complete(ptr);
```

In this case, the pointer *is* dangling, because the result of `Data::new()` [is stored in a temporary variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes) within the statement, which is dropped at the end of the statement, not [a local variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#scopes-of-local-variables), which is dropped at the end of the block.

If you want to adopt a programming style which makes explicit when values are dropped, the usual pattern is to use [the standard `drop()` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) to mark the exact time of drop:

```
    let data = Data::new();
    ...
    on_complete(data.to_raw());
    drop(data); // We have stopped using the raw pointer now
```

(Note that `drop()` is not magic: it is simply a function which takes one argument and does nothing with it other than dropping. Its presence in the standard library is to give a name to this pattern, not to provide special functionality.)

However, if you want to, there isn't anything wrong with using your `with_extended_lifetime` (other than nonstandard style and arguably a misleading name) if you want to make the code structure even more strongly indicate the scope of the value. One nitpick: the function parameter should be `FnOnce`, not `Fn`, for maximum generality (this allows it to be passed functions that *can't* be called more than once).

Comment: You exactly caught my mistake. Studying the crashing version of the code, I had done just what you said: `let ptr = Data::new().to_raw();`. That's a much easier kind of bug to code-review for since it is fairly obvious it puts a raw pointer to a temporary into a variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Other than explicitly dropping as the other answer mentions, there is another way to help prevent these types of accidental drops: use a wrapper around a raw pointer that has lifetime information.

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
#[repr(transparent)]
struct PtrWithLifetime<'a>{
   ptr: *mut ffi::c_void,
   _data: PhantomData<&'a ffi::c_void>,
}

impl Data {
    fn to_raw(&self) -> PtrWithLife<'_>{
        PtrWithLifetime{
            ptr: self.ptr,
            _data: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

The `#[repr(transparent)]` guarantees that `PtrWithLife` is stored in memory the same as `*const ffi::c_void` is, so you can adjust the declaration of `on_complete` to

```rust
fn called_from_c(on_complete: extern "C" fn(PtrWithLifetime<'_>)){
    //stuff
}
```

without causing any major inconvenience to any downstream users, especially since the ffi bindings can be adjusted in a similar fashion.

Comment: This seems like it would be almost identical to returning a reference (except for weaker validity invariants, such as possibly being null). What advantages do you see?

Comment: @KevinReid that's exactly what it is, a reference without any validity invariants. It's basically just returning the raw pointer, but harder to accidentally screw up (eg `let ptr = Data::new().to_raw; on_complete(ptr)` would be a compiler error instead of undefined behavior). Many safe wrappers around c libraries use some variant of this technique to ensure child objects don't outlive parent objects.